# How to monitor a long running operation with Ajax when web server is behind load balancer

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading, grails, websocket

I have a few Grails server instances running behind a load balancer that routes the requests to them in a round-robin fashion. The sessions are stored in redis and I don't have "sticky sessions" enabled in the load balancer (I'm running in AWS).

I'm running into problems in my admin view where I start a long running operation and want to show a progress bar about the operation. I had implemented it long ago by starting a thread for the long running operation and reporting progress information back to a service bean and then polling the progress status in the UI with a simple ajax request. This worked fine when i had the "sticky sessions" enabled because the status requests were routed to the same instance that had started the long running operation. Now that the status request can be routed to any instance I get random results. The other instances don't have a clue about the operation and thus report 0 progress.

And I know it's not a good idea to store this kind of status information in a service, but this is a maintenance operation that only I will run so I cut a few corners. Now I'm looking for a better way.

What is the "right" way to monitor long running operations when there are multiple server instances behind a load balancer? Should I open a web socket in the processing thread and report directly from there? Web sockets seem a bit heavy, but are they?

Comment: you say it's fine when you have sticky sessions, then maybe it will be fine if you have sessions replication ?

Comment: I am using web sockets for this.